# Source for a ssop to dip adapter?

Tags: prototyping, adapter

I need a prototyping adapter for a ssop 24-pin package. Google turns up plenty of dip adapters for 5-7mm chips, but the chip I have is 3.9mm across the body and 6mm to the tips of the pins.

Anyone know of source of a suitable adapter?  Doesn't necessarily have to be a dip, just something solderable by humans.

Comment: Are you sure it's SSOP? .65mm pitch?

Comment: What is the device?

Comment: Common package dimensions [here](http://www.national.com/packaging/parts/). Sounds like [TSSOP](http://www.national.com/packaging/mkt/mtc24.pdf).

Comment: Thanks.  The data sheets says SSOP, .650 spaced lands with nominal 5.3mm spcing for the centres of the lands. Silicon labs si4734/35. http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/Si4734-35-C40.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Standard SSOP](http://www.national.com/packaging/mkt/msa24.pdf) land pads should fit this device. 8.8mm from the extreme ends of the pads, width-wise, leaves 1.1mm on each side within which to solder, according to your 6mm measurement. [The breakout board on Sparkfun's site](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/500) looks like it has 1.5mm pads, but they just barely start at 6mm apart. These ones from Aries may be a better bet:

- http://www.arieselec.com/Web_Data_Sheets/18036/18036.htm
- http://www.arieselec.com/results.php?searchtype=3&partno=24-351000-10
- http://www.arieselec.com/results.php?searchtype=3&partno=24-351000-11
- http://www.arieselec.com/results.php?searchtype=3&partno=24-651000-10
- http://www.arieselec.com/results.php?searchtype=3&partno=28-555000-00

Comment: Thanks, they like they will do.  I looked at the sparkfun ones, but the rows looked a little far apart, as did others I'd found.

Answer (score 2):

Some other sites that might carry something suitable - I've not ordered from any of them so I can't endorse them personally, but I thought the links might be helpful.

- [proto-advantage.com](http://www.proto-advantage.com)
- [winslowadaptics.com](http://www.winslowadaptics.com)
- [schmartboard.com](http://www.schmartboard.com)
- [beldynsys.com](http://www.beldynsys.com)

Comment: Fixed that for you.  Welcome to the site!