# Breakout Board for 1.27 mm to 2.54 mm

Tags: integrated-circuit, packages

Is there any breakout board like [this](http://www.ehajo.de/Abverkauf/xQFP-Breakout-Board-0%2C65mm-142?source=2&refertype=2&referid=4) for 1.27 mm to 2.54 mm pitch?

Example for 1.27 mm:

[image]

Example for 2.54 mm:

[image]

I also appreciate any hint how to perform this conversion on any other cheap way.

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic, but you're looking for an SOIC to DIP adapter board.

Comment: Unless I found a really great price, this would be something that I'd order through http://oshpark.com/ once I found (or created) the appropriate Eagle/Kicad/whatever files.

Comment: I got some from Sparkfun, in Germany available through [Watterott](http://www.watterott.com/de/SOIC-DIP-Adapter-20-Pin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many!  http://www.futurlec.com/SMD_Adapters.shtml are perhaps the least expensive.  Digikey stocks [Surfboards](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?x=-942&y=-72&lang=en&site=us&KeyWords=surfboards).  My favorites are from http://www.proto-advantage.com/store/, who will actually order the IC for you and solder it down before shipping.

Answer (score 5):

This kind of breakout board is often called *breadboard adapter*.   Here's an example.

[image]

more details on manufacturer's web site: http://www.beldynsys.com/singledual.htm

more manufacturers: 
http://www.schmartboard.com/index.asp?page=products_so 
http://www.capitaladvanced.com/9000ser.htm

**edit**

[Old thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/8068/7036) on a similar subject.