# SMDs for Breadboards

Tags: surface-mount, breadboard

I'm looking at building an inductive charger (based on the design at http://people.oregonstate.edu/~watersal/documents/uhc_awaters.pdf), and there are a few components they use that are surface-mounted as opposed to the kind you can use in a breadboard (no idea what the name is...). I need help finding equivalents I can use in a breadboard. Any suggestions?

Here are the ICs in question:

- [LT6106](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/6106fa.pdf) (high-side current sense amplifier)
- [TPS62000-05](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slvs294e/slvs294e.pdf) (low-voltage step-down converter)

Any ideas whatsoever (or for that matter any suggestions for how to use surface-mounted ICs on a breadboard) would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: May I urge you to provide a link to a document that gets right to the point of what you are trying to do. This looks like some thesis and I got bored rapidly. Maybe just spell-out what it is you are attempting. I know you are looking for leaded components BTW - have you looked at Linear Tech's website and the one for the TPS thing?

Comment: Maybe also indicate what you are trying to achieve with this design because there are certainly alternatives that might do what you want that are definitely simpler to build

Comment: Related thread: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/61824/7036

Comment: Components you can use on a breadboard are generally called "Through-Hole", since they have leads that are intended to poke through the holes in the circuit-board they will eventually be used in. The opposite (e.g. components that mount only on the surface of a board) are called, unsurprisingly, "surface-mount". The two are sometimes abbreviated TH and SMT respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need are break-out boards. They are small boards to which you solder your surface-mount device, and they have pins on 0.1" centers so you can plug them into a breadboard. One example is Bellin Dynamic Systems [1](http://www.beldynsys.com/singledual.htm). By the way, the opposite of surface-mount is usually called "through-hole".

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, thanks for the info. Do you know if there are any good alternatives to those ICs that are through-hole by default?

Comment: @ramchand917 Sorry, I don't understand your question. Do you mean alternative methods of mounting them or alternative parts that you can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://www.datasheets.com/) website to compare and find similar parts with different specifications(SMD - DIP - packaging - .... etc ) .

This is an example from your question :
http://www.datasheets.com/search/description/high-side-sp-current-sp-sense-sp-amplifier

You can surf the website and explore the great free service there .