# Working with a tiny IC

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, soldering, breadboard, socket

I have recently purchased several Atmel's touch sensor IC's [AT42QT1010](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-9541-AT42-QTouch-BSW-AT42QT1010_Datasheet.pdf) which are extremely tiny (1.6mm x 2.9mm) and I would like to be able to mount them on a breadboard. I have tried soldering them to a PCB but I just can't solder that precisely so I always end up soldering the pins to each other.

Is there any IC socket (or anything else) that would increase its size or at least the space between the pins?

Comment: a breakout pcb adapter for it would be the best. This seems to be a good training opportunity for such small things (and maybe opportunity to tune your equipment)

Comment: As @Plasma had mentioned above, the thing you are looking for is called *breadboard adapter*.  Here's an old thread with a thorough discussion about breadboard adapters:  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/61824/7036

Comment: Have you tried using a pick or if you don't have one jam a pin or needle into a pencil eraser and use that to clear your solder bridges when you make them?

Comment: 0.95mm pitch is not all that fine- breakouts are really cheap- that's the way to go. I suggest tacking the package on the corners and use fine solder to solder, and use some fresh fine solder wick if you short the leads. It sucks the solder bridges away very readily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you got the SOT23-6.  Could be worse, they do make chips in even smaller leaded packages, and extremely small leadless packages.  They don't make sockets for chips this small, possibly aside from expensive and very bulky ZIF sockets.  These chips are just meant to be soldered down onto a board.  I would recommend getting a breakout board that will convert this chip to a DIP form factor for breadboarding.  Just search on ebay for sot23 adapter and you'll find a bunch of breakout boards, make sure you get one with the correct pin pitch.  You'll have to solder the chip to the breakout board yourself, but once it's on there you should be good to go.

Comment: This is veering dangerously into shopping advice territory, but if you're not all that experienced in soldering, schmartboard adaptors might be particularly convenient to use: http://www.schmartboard.com/index.asp?page=products_smttodip&id=450

Comment: Yup, it is SOT23-6. I've found an adapter on [sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/717). I wanted to avoid soldering since I am not very good at it (especially with such a tiny things) but I guess I'll have to practice .. :)

Comment: Yeah, practice makes perfect.  If you don't have one already, get a decent iron with a very fine point.

Comment: SOT23-6 is big :P Just make liberal use of a flux pen.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success soldering these onto a small piece of veroboard using thin copper wire to contact the actual leads, and some .1" headers to make legs. It helps somewhat to bend the four outer leads to the side (be careful! only bend them once or you stand a good chance of breaking them off) so that it's easier to reach the middle legs.

Pictures is of a SOT-23 part, but it's the same deal.

[image]

That said, if you end up soldering the legs together then your problem may be that your soldering iron is too large. If you intend using parts like these - which you often have to because all the good stuff is in tiny packages - then it's a good idea to invest in a decent soldering iron with a fine tip and plenty of power (so it can heat up solder with just the tip).

Also: Solder wick. Don't attempt this without it.

Answer (score 0):

Proto-advantage.Com will sell you a breakout adapter pcb, with legs, and will even order your chip and solder it down for you at very reasonable cost.