# 4 or 8 channel Analog Switch IC

Tags: voltage, pcb, switches, integrated-circuit, circuit-design

I'm looking at analog switches to control 40-50 switches. Since its a prototype, I am looking at DIP packages on breadboard for the analog switches, then resuse them on the PCB when its fabricated.

Why does the quad channel chip cost so much cheaper ($0.43) compared to the octal channel chip ($4.60)? Going from 4 to 8 switches require a 10X increase in cost.

**Quad:** [SN74HC4066N](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/SN74HC4066N/296-8329-5-ND/376726)

**Octal:** [MAX395CNG+](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=MAX395CNG)

Comment: The MAX chip is smarter (SPI controlled), where the TI chip is just some digital logic. These are two very different chips.

Comment: The reality is that the DIP packages are a thing of the past.  Thus, you should learn SMT soldering to some level.  Start with SOIC packages, then MSSOP and QSOP and QFP, then maybe QFN.  Leave BGA to trained PCB assembly professionals (at least for now).  The [SMT breadboard adapters](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/61824/7036) make a good playground for SMT soldering practice, and you can use them for breadboarding too.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed. It is not asking for people to recommend products or where to buy them, it's asking why one chip costs more than another, which is a much more general question. It is something that can be applicable to a number of products - it is important to *read the specifications* before comparing the prices of parts to ensure they are comparable.

Comment: What are your switching?  voltage ? signals? current?

Comment: If you are using the 4066 with +/-5V supplies you will have to control it with +/-5V logic inputs. The M*x*m chip includes level shifting that works over a narrow range of supplies. The HC4066 is built with a standard CMOS process and has limitations as a result. Much better chips than the M*x*m exist that can work over wider voltage ranges with low charge injection and resistance and perhaps protection, however the price may be approaching two orders of magnitude higher than the HCMOS part rather than just one ($5 in 1k pieces rather than less than 10 cents).

Comment: The 74HC4066 IC is an upgrade from the original CD4066 IC that came on the market in the 1970's. It is very low cost because it is still in use and made by several manufactures. The MAX IC belongs to Max alone, so they set the market price.

Comment: Why are some cars really cheap whilst others cost a lot yet they all have four wheels? No research on the parts means this question should be closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows lack of research into the subject matter.

Answer (score 4):

For one thing, without even looking at the datasheets, you're looking at completely different manufacturers. They likely have different features included that significantly impact the price. If you want comparable prices, you need to find 4- and 8-channel switches in the *same series* from the *same manufacturer*.

For another thing, after opening the datasheets I see the MAX chip is controlled over a serial connection whereas the TI chip is controlled using a simple digital HI/LO signal. The way these chips behave are completely different, you are trying to compare apples to oranges.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I know to pay better attention to how the chip is being controlled. The datasheets are overwhelming to me right now, trying to get used to them.

Comment: @AthenaWisdom Most times a beginner can look at the first page and be able to identify what sets one part apart from another. The information I posted is all shown right on the front page, which shouldn't be very overwhelming.