# Soldering SOT-23

Tags: soldering, breadboard, prototyping, packages

I'm working on a DYI [battery monitor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/212723/96746) project and the possibility of using an [INA169](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina169.pdf) came up. That's a SOT-23 packaged component.

I have minimal soldering skills so I'm looking for some advice:

Can I solder this with 0.031" solder? It's the skinniest I have.

What kind of board do I solder it to? Currently I'm breadboard only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I solder this with 0.031" solder? It's the skinniest I have.

0.031" is a bit fat for soldering SOT-23-5, but you may be able to do it.  I would recommend 0.015" .

> What kind of board do I solder it to? Currently I'm breadboard only.

The sort of board that you solder an SMT component to for breadboarding is called *breadboard adapter*.  See old threads: [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/61824/7036) and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8068/source-for-a-ssop-to-dip-adapter).  Breadboard adapters for SOT-23-5 are not hard to come by ([this](http://uk.farnell.com/capital-advanced/33205/adaptor-ic-sot23-5-sc59-5/dp/1654363) and [this](http://www.proto-advantage.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=2400052) for example).

Answer (score 5):

It's doable.

Put a little solder on middle pad of the SOT-23 of the PCB, then, while keeping the solder liquid move the part into place. Let the part cool down, it'll be fixed on the single middle pin now.

Next, put a little bit of solder on the tip of your soldering iron and transfer it to the other two pads, one after another.

If you screw up you can clean the solder with solder-wick or with tiny pieces of copper litz wire.

Good tools and a flux-pen are more important than the solder itself. For best results you need a good tweezer and a magnifier.

Comment: That assumes I have a PCB already printed out with pads for my SOT-23 chip, right?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you solder it to a [proto-board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/8812) or buy some of these [adapters](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/717). Make sure you have a fine tip on your soldering iron and a microscope always helps but a magnifying glass works too if you don't feel like investing in one. Since you don't have much soldering experience I would also suggest you try a dot of epoxy to hold the SOT23 package in place before you try to solder the leads.