# Sensors for PIC microcontrollers

Tags: pic, sensor

I recently started working with PIC Micro-controllers and I am thinking of working on a project to get a hands-on experience. I am looking to interface a few sensors with the PIC via the EUSART and I2C protocols. Can someone suggest me any such sensors that can be easily plugged into a breadboard (has a DIP type package), so that I can unplug them easily in case I mess up electrical connections? I did find some sensors online (e.g. MS5611 barometer) however, this IC can not be plugged into a breadboard (its a surface mount type).

Note: It doesn't matter what the sensor measures. I'm looking for a DIP type package and something that can be interfaced via RS232/I2C protocol

Comment: (option 1) Learn how to do SMT soldering.  Get some SMT breadboard adapters (more on that [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/8068/7036) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/61824/7036)).  Now you can breadboard SMT chips.  SMT soldering is an increasingly useful skill, because throughole components are going extinct.

Comment: (option 2) Go to the IC supplier's web site.  There probably is a [sensors section](https://www.mouser.com/Sensors/_/N-5gej/).  Filter for throughole packages, and I2C.

Comment: (option 3) If you only want to play with I2C, UART you can choose some other type of IC, besides sensors.  I/O expanders, EEPROMs, 7-segment LED character drivers can give you decent hands-on exposure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider going to some supplier such as Adafruit and looking at breakout boards that have the sensors on a small PCB. Many of the sensors you might be interested in have inconveniently small packages.

It's inappropriate here to recommend any specific product, but a few weeks ago a colleague was preparing to interface to a very expensive satellite component and wanted to practice on something disposable- I suggested a small board based on a Bosch temperature/humidity sensor that used the I2C bus and cost less than $20 USD. Such boards are typically designed to be possible to plug into a 2.54mm pitch solderless breadboard.